# Show a modalViewController after image picking

Tags: iphone

I want to present a modalViewController(do some picture drawing) right after dismiss the imagePickerController(exactly after finish image picking). I've tried to set up a IBAction with a bar button and it works fine when I tap it. But what I want is present the modalViewController as soon as I finish the image picking
Here is my code:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePicerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info{

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
    //dismiss the imagePickerController
    drawViewController *drawView = [[drawViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentModalViewController:drawView animated:YES];
  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dismiss and presentModal can't both animate in the same method.  The presentModal will seem to do nothing.  For the dismiss, try setting the animated to NO.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the solution you just gave, it works perfect now!

Answer (score 0):

After dissmissing the imagePickerController the viewDidAppear is called. You can there call the drawViewcontroller.

```
    -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
       drawViewController *drawView = [[drawViewController alloc] init];
       [self presentModalViewController:drawView animated:YES];

    }
```